# Getting the number of rows in an NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I get the total number of rows in an NSOutlineView?

Comment: Excuse my pedantry but "amount" should be "number" since it's something that can be definitely counted and represented with an integer.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to get the number of rows from your data source?

Comment: Yes, I mean number not amount.

Comment: Your data source would have to know how many rows worth of data it contains before anything could be drawn on the screen. Ask it.

Comment: What method would you use to ask the data source? I can't seem to find a method in the NSOutlineViewDataSource protocol reference. By the way this question has nothing to do with drawing on the screen. I just need to know the amount of rows in my Outline View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this include any subordinate rows in expanded rows? For example, if foo contains bar, baz, and qux, and is expanded, then bar, baz, and qux are visible rows as well. Conversely, if foo is not expanded, then bar, baz, and qux are not “rows in [the] NSOutlineView”—they exist only in your model.

Forget the outline view. It is irrelevant and confuses your question. You want to know how many of your model objects you have, so ask the controller that owns them.

People are saying “ask the data source” because that controller is the object that should be your view's data source. But forget the outline view, and forget its data source property. Talk to the controller directly. Ask it how many whatever-model-objects it has. If you want to know the deep version of the answer (how many things you have, including things in other things), ask it that. Either way, also implement a method in that controller to provide the answer.

Addendum: Remember [the separation of powers in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). You have a model, which is the user's data in object form; views, which display the model to the user; and controllers, which own the model and the views. You say this isn't a drawing-related question; that makes it a question not for a view (“how many rows will you draw”), but a question for a controller (“how many <some-kind-of-thing>s do you own”). Therefore, you need to ask it of a controller.

Comment: True. This is what I've decided to do based on your answer. I have done a fetch request from the model object and then got the arrays count. Here … http://grab.by/1jKg. Is this what you were thinking? It works.

Comment: It's not what I was thinking, but I'm not a Core Data guy. As far as I can tell, that's close enough. (BTW, don't ignore warnings. That warning is important. It also affects the line before it, which uses the correct formatter for the type you're using but the wrong formatter for the type you should be using.)

Comment: Peter's lecture is far too confined and opinionated. While it may be helpful to a certain audience it does not answer the literal question asked.  Michael's answer should suffice.  Learning the current number of rows, which Apple does provide as an API according to Michael below, can be invaluable to developers learning to understand exactly what NSOutlineView is doing.  Lecturing about MVC is not very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

there is a method called numberOfRows, which returns a NSInteger.
e.g. your NSOutlineView is called outlineView:

```
NSInteger *rows = [outlineView numberOfRows];
```

Documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/

"Typically you should not ask the table view how many rows it has; instead you should interrogate the table view's data source."

There is an informal protocol, if you are really insistent on using the tableView, which is:

```
– numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableDataSource informal protocol)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question - which returns the number of visible rows in the outlineview (ignoring items in the model which are not visible due not being expanded.)

Comment: I took the liberty of pointing the answer's documentation URL to superclass NSTableView (the link was broken anyway), where -numberOfRows is defined. It does return the number of visible rows in an NSOutlineView (tested in 10.13.3), although I don't feel we are 100% guaranteed this will always work for outline as opposed to table.